# Como Hacer una matriz simetrica en Python

Tags: python

Tengo este ejercicio en Python, pero me da un error en un IF, si me pudieran ayudar corrigiéndolo, más en concreto donde se encuentra el comentario en el If:

```
def leer (self):
    print("Digite el numero de filas")
    self.filas = int(input())

    print("Digite el numero de columnas")
    self.columnas = int(input())

    for i in range (self.filas):
        for j in range(self.columnas):
            filas = []
            print("Ingrese el digito: ")
            a=int(input())
            filas.append(a)
            self.numeros.append(filas)

    if( self.filas == self.columnas):
        for i in range(self.filas):
            for j in range(self.columnas):
                if (self.numeros[i][j] == self.numeros[j][i]) : #AQUI
                    self.band = 'V'

    if (self.band == 'V'):
        print("La matriz es simetrica")
    else:
        print("La matriz no es simetrica")
```

mat = Matriz()
mat.leer()

Comment: [*] solo hace falta un par diferente para romper la simetria

Comment: Esa línea sólo funciona con matrices cuadradas. Con una matriz rectangular (2x10, por ejemplo), estarías comparando `self.numeros[1][9] == self.numeros[9][1]` , lo que está fuera de rango.